# vue js evaluating a variable when passed to a component

Tags: components, vue.js

i wonder if this cant be done but i need some advice. I have a Vue JS component as follows

```
  <media class="u-media-top u-padding Media--secondary t-borderleft-{{FetchCompanyName()}} t-borderbottom" title="School Name">
    {{organisation}}
  </media>
```

and inside the component i have

```
<template><div class="Media" v-bind:class="class">....
```

so as you can see i pass a list of classes to the component and with in the component bind them all to the HTML. all is good. However i want my variable (which is a string returned from a mixin)

```
FetchCompanyName()
```

to be evaluated (i expect to see t-borderleft-companyA) after it is passed through to my component. as it currently stands when it loads i see

```
 t-borderleft-{{FetchCompanyName()}}
```

as i assume its just passing it though as a string. Can anyone give me advice on how i would achieve what i want?

Cheers Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<media :class="'t-borderleft-' + FetchCompanyName()" class="u-media-top u-padding Media--secondary t-borderbottom" title="School Name">
    {{organisation}}
</media>
```

You should also remove the `v-bind:class="class"` inside your component.

You could also try to make `FetchCompanyName` a computed property